# issues using code after exporting mssql to sqllite

Tags: perl, sqlite, template-toolkit, dancer

I am trying to shift a website from using a MS-SQL database to SQLite. I have therefore exported the MS-SQL database to SQLite and connected it successfully with Dancer, the lightweight Perl web framework which uses Template Toolkit.

I now have an issue with the FOREACH loops. Data is being passed as usual - as tested with the debug to_dumper($test) statement - but TT does not show it. Are you aware of any differences between MS-SSQL and SQLite? Other FOREACH loops also appear to have the same non display of data issue.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

a tail on the data passed is:

```
{
    'OneLiner' => 'Cruise on the Kerala backwaters',
    'Meta_Descr' => 'Get inspired by the trip ideas on our Traveller\'s Palm website. We are passionate about India and will be delighted to help you in designing your own tailor-made tour.',
    'PageName' => 'Popular Tours',
    'Introduction' => 'Tried and tested by thousands of clients over thirty years, these tours are the classics that always deliver. Tweaked and perfected based on our clients\' feedback these tours give you that perfect introduction to India or are the quickest way to travel between your old favourites. Rajasthan, Kerala, Goa and North India all feature on these tours and with good reason.

  We\'d also be happy to make any personalized changes or additions to these itineraries if you so choose and add your personal twist to these well-loved highlights.',
    'Meta_Title' => 'Popular Tours - Experience India | Traveller\'s Palm',
    'url' => 'popular-tours',
    'Themes_id' => 7,
    'Meta_Keywords' => 'popular holidays india, tailor-made popular india tours, popular india custom tour'
  },
  {
    'Meta_Title' => 'Romance - Experience India | Traveller\'s Palm',
    'Introduction' => 'Muslin draped four poster bed or a gently moving boat in the tropical backwaters? Tracking a tiger or exploring a working farm? Your romantic getaway can be what you want it to be; a sybaritic time with your beloved or an active and adventurous time shared with your spouse.',
    'Meta_Descr' => 'Get inspired by the trip ideas on our Traveller\'s Palm website. We are passionate about India and will be delighted to help you experience the romance of travel in India.',
    'PageName' => 'Romance',
    'OneLiner' => 'Looking for a romantic getaway',
    'Meta_Keywords' => 'romantic holidays india, tailor-made india romantic holidays, india honeymoon tour',
    'Themes_id' => 12,
    'url' => 'romance'
  }
]; in /home/user/webapps/travelo/lib/xxx/MemcacheDB.pm l. 1483
```

the memcached query is identical as used with the MS-SQL based site:

```
sub themes {
return memcached_get_or_set('themes',sub {
my $qry =  "SELECT pagename,introduction,url, oneliner,
                    meta_title,meta_descr,meta_keywords,themes_id
             FROM themes";

my $test = database('sqlserver')
            ->selectall_arrayref( $qry, { Slice => {} } );
debug to_dumper($test);
return $test;
});
}
```

The relevant html section in TT is:

```
    <ul class="slides image-box style1">
      [% FOREACH theme in themes %]
      <li>
        <article class="box">
          <figure>
            <a class="hover-effect" title="[% theme.title %]" href="[% request.uri_base %]/destinations/[% country %]/[% THEMES %]/[% theme.url %]">
             <img width="270" height="160" alt="" src="[% IMAGE %]/themes/themes_[% theme.themes_id %].jpg" />
           </a>
         </figure>
         <div class="details">
          <h4 class="box-title">[% theme.pagename %]</h4>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    [% END %]
  </ul>
```

Comment: it's been a while, but could this be a case of case-sensitivity? I see that in the `TT` template you have lower-case, but in the hashref, you have upper-case. MS has a history of not caring or deciphering...

Comment: Side-question: Why not use DBIC and let that take care of your switching needs?

Comment: I second @stevieb 's idea. What does the datastructure look like that comes of the MSSQL query?

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was indeed cases sensitivity in SQLite which was not there with MS_SQL.